# Mixing php with javascript.Toggle reveal /hide fetched data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

This is the update page, where the customer shopping basket content is displayed. The shopping details are kept in 'mcart' table.
It consists of mcartId,mcookieId,mpr,mqty,mpn & des fields.
The main part number,prices,description & priced discounts are taken from table2.
    Typical update page will look this:

```
p-n price   qty remove? qty discounts

s-12    10.25   1   remove  Items

b-12    3.64    1   remove  Items

'Items' contains discount range which is fetched from another table                     e.g.
Items:
1-5 ,0%

6-19 ,12%

20-39 ,25%

40-59 ,33%

60-99 ,37%

100-199 ,42%

200-499 ,45%

500-9999 ,48%
```

These discount rates are hidden and will be revealed once a user clicks on 'items' to toggle hide or reveal.
eg, if customer buys 1-5 item price would be say £2.50, but 6-9, will eb reduced to say £1.90 and so on.
The discount range is hidden and should ideally reveal it for any item they click on, under 'item'.
At present it only shows the discounts for the 1st item, as I would expect, no matter which item I choose.
How can I change the javascript, so it would remember which item I have clicked on and show only that item's discount percentage?
Please help!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function toggle(id){
  var e=document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == '') 
  {
   e.style.display = 'none'; 
 } 
else {
e.style.display = '';
 }
}
 </script>

  <?php 


//     ====== Connection to database ==============================
include("order/connection.php");    


//   ============== identify if item has been removed or qty  changed=> whats the part number? =========

$id = $_GET[id];

$mqty = $_POST[chmqty];

$mpn = $_POST[mmpn];



    //     ================If qty has been changed ==============

    if (isset($_POST['chmqty']))
       {

 $stmt = $pd->prepare('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE 
  part_number=:part_number'  );
 $stmt->execute(array(':part_number' => $mpn));
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);



  //     ====== Get the correct price break =====================

    for($in =1 ; $in <= 8; $in++)


    {
                            $bb=$row["price_break".($in)];
                            $halves =explode("-",$bb);
                            $firstnumber=$halves[0];
                            $secondnumber=$halves[1];


                                If ($mqty >= $firstnumber && $mqty <=  
 $secondnumber)
                                {

                                $price= 
 number_format($row[("price_each".$in)], 2, ".", ",");


                                }
        }
//     ================================


$query = "UPDATE mcart SET mqty='$mqty', mpr='$price'

WHERE mcookieId = :cookie AND mpn= :part";
$stmt3=$pd->prepare($query);
$stmt3->BindValue(':cookie',$_COOKIE[mcartId], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt3->BindValue(':part',$_POST[mmpn], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt3->execute();

}




// =============== If DELETE button has been pressed ======


if (!empty($id))
 {

$statement2= 'DELETE  FROM mcart WHERE  mcookieId=? AND mpn=?';

$stmt1 = $pd->prepare($statement2);

$stmt1->execute(array($_COOKIE[mcartId],$id));

}




// ================= Display customer Shopping Basket ==========

$statement= "SELECT * FROM mcart WHERE  mcookieId=:cookie";

$stmt2 = $pd->prepare($statement);

$stmt2->bindParam(':cookie', $_COOKIE[mcartId], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt2->execute();


?>



<Table class="tupdate">
<tr >
<th  class="pn"> p-n
</th>



<th  class="pr"> price
</th>


<th  class="qty"> qty
    </th>



    <th  class="remove"> remove?
    </th>


<th  class="disc">discounts
    </th>


</tr> 


<?php

while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo "<tr  class='basket1'>";



// ================ Show Part Numbers ===============
echo "<td class='basket1'>";
echo $row['mpn'];
echo "</td>";





    // ================ Show Proces ===============

    echo "<td class='basket1'>";
   echo $row['mpr'];
  echo "</td>";

    echo "<form method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>";


   // ===== Show Qty already in shopping basket that can be changed,
  // =====get   qty & partnumber if update is clicked ======
   echo "<td class='basket1'>";

echo "<input  type='number'  size='3'  value='".$row['mqty']."'     
name='chmqty' class='chmqty'>" ;


echo "<input type='hidden' name='mmpn' value='".$row['mpn']."'>";

echo" <Input  type='submit' value='update'>";

echo "</form>";
echo "</td>";


  // == An item can be removed from basket, get the part number ===
echo "<td class='basket1'>";


echo "<a href='update1.php?id="

.$row['mpn'].

"'>remove</a>";

echo "</td>";

    // ===== Show the price break range and associated   discount 
percentage from Table2 ====
echo "<td class='basket1'>";
?>

 <a href="#" onclick="toggle('objDetails')">Items</a>
  <span id="objDetails" style="display:none">



  <?php

  //     ====== calculate how many times in basket and the total 
price so far =====

    $totq=$row["mqty"];


    $totqty=$totqty+$totq;


    $totp=$row["mqty"]*$row["mpr"];
    $totpr=$totpr+$totp;



  //     ====== Connect to Table 2, Find the relevant p-n and its 
discount percentage and lis it =========


$stmt = $pd->prepare("SELECT * FROM table2 LEFT JOIN mcart ON 
table2.part_number = mcart.mpn WHERE table2.part_number 
=:part_number");


$stmt->execute(array(':part_number' => $row['mpn']));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);




        $c=$row["price_each1"];//  price for single item


                            for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
                            {

                            $b=$row["price_each".$i];


                            if ($b !=0.00)
                                {

                                $d=(($c-$b)/$c)*100;

            $complete=$row[("price_break".$i)]. " ," .round($d)."%";


                            echo"</br>";
                            echo $complete;
                                echo"</br>";

                                    }
                                }


                                echo "</span>";


   echo "</td>";

    //}


   }
?>
</tr>
<table >

 <tr >

<!--   <td ><?php   //echo "Total purchases: ".$total."for part  
number".$_POST["mpn"];?> </td>  -->
<th  class="basket2"> </th>
<th class="basket1"><?php   echo "Total of &pound;".$totpr;?> </th>

<th colspan="2" class="basket2"><?php echo "for ".$totqty." items";?>  
</th>
  <th  class="basket3"> <img src="/stampede/images/scart.jpg"  
alt="Shopping Cart" width="20">  </th>
  </tr>

</table>

<?php 
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";


 include ("order/options1.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: Add some of your html code please

Comment: Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. You have to pass variable via URL string to the new page.
I used the example below:

INSIDE "page1.php" or "page1.html"

```
// Send the variables myNumber=1 and myFruit="orange" to the new PHP page...
<a href="page2c.php?myNumber=1&myFruit=orange">Send variables via URL!</a>
```

INSIDE "page2c.php"

```
<?php
    // Retrieve the URL variables (using PHP).
    $num = $_GET['myNumber'];
    $fruit = $_GET['myFruit'];
    echo "Number: ".$num."  Fruit: ".$fruit;
?>
```